How to handle an error thrown by an asynchronous function?
This is not a duplicate to this question since it discusses rejecting promises. This is about errors that are thrown. It is also worth mentioning that I can't modify the behavior of the mpv.getProperty function. Please re-open this question.
I'm using an async function mpv.getProperty (see documentation here)
This function sometimes throws an error and not a rejection to the promise, so I cannot simply use a .catch block after the async call.
I've tried wrapping it around a try-catch block but that didn't work. I also tried writing a wrapper for it and calling it instead of the function directly as so:
app.get('/filename', (req, res) => {
    async function getFilenameProperty() {
        try {
            return await mpv.getProperty("filename")
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    getFilenameProperty().then((f) => {
        res.status(200).send(f)
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(400).send(`Error getting filename`)
    })
})
}

Why isn't this working? What's the best practice way to handle this error?
To reproduce this error, create an express server with the node-mpv library imported including the /filename endpoint as shown above:
const mpv = new mpvAPI({"verbose": true}, ["--fullscreen"])
const app = express()

If you perform a GET request to the endpoint, the server crashes instead of handling the error gracefully.
Thanks!
Edit: this is the error being thrown if that gives any clue as to how the error can be handled:
node:events:495
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_SOCKET_CLOSED]: Socket is closed
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (node:net:953:8)
    at Socket._write (node:net:975:8)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10)
    at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10)
    at /hot/GitHub/remotetv-fullstack-project/back/node_modules/node-mpv/lib/ipcInterface/ipcInterface.js:209:17
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at ipcInterface.send (/hot/GitHub/remotetv-fullstack-project/back/node_modules/node-mpv/lib/ipcInterface/ipcInterface.js:190:10)
    at ipcInterface.getProperty (/hot/GitHub/remotetv-fullstack-project/back/node_modules/node-mpv/lib/ipcInterface/ipcInterface.js:117:15)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'ERR_SOCKET_CLOSED'
}


No, it's not. I can't copy and paste the code snippet to reproduce the problem. Why is it necessary to use Express and an external library? Is it not possible to reproduce the problem without it?

@jabaa OK, I'll make a new post then if it should be more general. The issue is that I can't catch it before await since I can't (or shouldn't at least) modify the code for mpv.getProperty

Don't use try catch block inside async. instead just write:
async function getFilenameProperty() {     return await mpv.getProperty("filename"); }
async functions automatically reject Promise on error

Just removing try catch block inside async function getFilenameProperty will fix your problem

@Sparrow That still doesn't work. I don't think I fully understand what is happening for this error to pop up actually. Since it's a socket closed error maybe it's an OS thing?

Can you clarify what that means? I thought it was already catching the error before the await

Still doesn't work unfortunately

Then, the error is thrown somewhere else. That's why we need a [mcve].

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
